# Storing a string from a pipe to a struct in C

Tags: arrays, c, pipe

I am struggling with a relatively trivial problem.

In my C program I have defined a

Struct Trader

```
    struct trader {
    int pid;
    char *order[1000];
    int number_of_orders;
};
```

I have a list of trader struct called traders

```
struct trader traders[50];
```

I read some contents from a pipe and store it in a my read_input array

I have a for loop that iterates through my trader array of size 50, reads the value of a pipe, stores it in an array.

I wish to transfer this array into my traders[i].orders variable and store it in that.

So each trader can have multiple values stored for example the number of orders counts the amount of values read from the pipe

Initially it is 0, since that is the first read, and it increments each time a read from pipe occurs.

If my pipe reads in the value "hello", it will store it in the first position (0) in my traders[i].order[number_of_orders] array, and if it reads another value it will store it in the second position traders[i].order[number_of_orders] where number_of_orders  = 1.

```
for(int i = 0; i< sizeof(traders) / sizeof(struct trader); ++i){
        if(child_pid == traders[i].pid){
            int pip_read = read(fdTrader, read_input, sizeof read_input);
            read_input[pip_read] = '\0';
            read_input[strlen(read_input)-1] = '\0';

            if(traders[i].number_of_orders < 1000){
                strcpy(traders[i].order[traders[i].number_of_orders], read_input);
                traders[i].number_of_orders++;
            }


            
            write(fdExchange, "ACCEPTED 0;", strlen("ACCEPTED 0;"));
            kill(child_pid, SIGUSR1);
            init_orderbook(i,read_input,traders[i]);
        }
    }



==60==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0x000000000000 (pc 0x7f23dd6a7166 bp 0x7ffedaee18f0 sp 0x7ffedaee18c8 T0)
==60==The signal is caused by a WRITE memory access.
==60==Hint: address points to the zero page.
```

The following code gives me this error

**EDIT**

I have altered my code In my main method

I am doing this

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++) {
        traders[i].order[j] = malloc(50 * sizeof(char));
    }
}
```

Iterating my traders list, and setting each order pointer to point to a area of 50 bytes?

Is this okay?

Comment: `int pip_read = read(fdTrader, read_input, sizeof read_input);  read_input[pip_read] = '\0';` is bad as it writes the _null character_ outside `read_input[]`.  Best to post a [mcve].

Comment: `char *order[1000];` gives you 1000 char **pointers** but I don't see any `malloc` like calls. Where do you allocate memory for holding the strings? You need code similar to `VAR.order[i] = malloc[STR_LEN + 1];`

Comment: Further... are you sure that `read` will give you exactly one string? Study https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html

Comment: I have not done this step, do you mind showing me how I can intialize my order array to point to strings of 128 characters?

Comment: Better do the `malloc` just prior to the assignment - and use `strlen(...)+1` instead of that constant.

Answer (score 0):

Your `orders` field is an array of 1000 **pointers** - and these aren't automatically initialized.  Depending on how you allocated your "traders", it's either all NULL pointers or random garbage.

The `strcpy()` function expects it's first argument to point to allocated memory that it can write to.

To fix this, you need to `malloc()` the `traders[i].order[traders[i].number_of_orders]` prior to calling `strcpy`.

If you want to avoid the allocations, then you could use a helper struct, such as for instance

```
struct order_data {
   char text[128];
};
```

and then do

```
    order_data order[1000];
```

That gives you a fixed array of 1000 `order_data` elements each containing a fixed-length string.

Comment: I have edited my code, this should be okay right?

Comment: Yes - but I would call `malloc()` just prior to the `strcpy()` and use the actual size - `strlen()+1` - for it.  You don't really want to call malloc in a loop up-front to allocate a bunch of stuff that you may never need.